# How can it be proved that (S)-bis-[2-(t-butylsulfinyl)phenyl] diselenide is a chiral non-racemic product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

I read in paper that:

> The aim of this part of the work was to synthesise new aromatic diselenides with chiral phosphorous or sulfoxide centres in coordinative distance to the selenium as precursors for new chiral selenenylating reagents.

How can it be proved that (*S*)-bis-[2-(t-butylsulfinyl)phenyl]diselenide is a chiral non-racemic product?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking how, experimentally they determined that the product is chiral, or why, theoretically, it should be so?

Comment: Chould you please add the paper, that your are citing? And welcome to chemistry.se!

Comment: That's some hardcore you've got there ;) , it seems not googlable so you really should provide link or more details

Comment: I want to know how I can assign that  this product has (S) or (R) chirality

Comment: This'll be easier if we can see the structure.

Comment: How can I insert the structure of this product  in this site , please ???

Comment: @Nado: You can upload a picture containing the structure.

Comment: @Nado AFAIK, you can't upload an image because your reputation doesn't allow it. If it is so, you could put a link to it and we'll edit and add the image for you.

Answer (score 6):

Compounds with the general structure $\ce{R-SO-R'}$, i.e. containing a sulfinyl $\ce{-SO-{}}$ functional group attached to two carbon atoms, are called generically ‘sulfoxides’. Sulfoxides may be considered as a tetrahedral system composed of a central atom, ligands, and a lone pair of electrons (or phantom atom).

[image: sulfoxide]

When the two organic residues $\ce{R}$ and $\ce{R'}$ are dissimilar, the sulfur atom is a stereogenic center.

The compound bis[2-(*tert*-butylsulfinyl)phenyl]diselenide contains two chiral sulfinyl groups and thus two stereogenic centers.

[image: bis[2-(tert-butylsulfinyl)phenyl]diselenide]

Therefore, three stereoisomers exist:

- bis[2-((*R*)-*tert*-butylsulfinyl)phenyl]diselenide,

  [image: R,R]
- bis[2-((*S*)-*tert*-butylsulfinyl)phenyl]diselenide,

  [image: S,S]
- and the meso compound [2-((*R*)-*tert*-butylsulfinyl)phenyl][2-((*S*)-*tert*-butylsulfinyl)phenyl]diselenide

  [image: R,S]

Comment: Now it's very clear . Thank you so much Prof with my best regards  to  you .